# Calling Present on View Fails with modally active controller error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When calling present on a hamburger menu, it succeeds on the first load but fails on the second.

Once the app launches you log in. It then calls the listener to perform actions after log in. You can click the burger menu on the left and it works. Now, if you log out, log back in and then hit the burger menu again, it throws the error `Application tried to present modally an active controller HomePageViewController`. It seems as if something was loaded correctly when the app first loads and it's trying to do it again which is causing to fail. I can't figure out what. Any help would be appreciated here. I've included AppDelegate.swift and AppController.swift which both are relevant here.

```swift
    @objc func burgerButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        present(SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

*AppDelegate.swift*

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        AppController.sharedInstance.enableCognitoClientWithAuthentication()

        // setup logging


        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        AppController.sharedInstance.launchInWindow(aWindow: self.window)

        let signedIn = AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().isSignedIn
        self.navigationController = UINavigationController()
        if !signedIn {
            navigationInit()

        } else {
            AppController.sharedInstance.showLoggedInStateAndReturn(true)
        }

                //pool.delegate = self


        return true
    }

    func navigationInit() {

        let loginViewController = LoginViewController()
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: false)


    }
```

*AppController.swift*

```swift
class AppController: NSObject {
    func launchInWindow(aWindow: UIWindow?){

        self.window = aWindow
        self.initializeSDKs()
        self.globalCustomization()
        self.AWSUnAuthedClient.apiKey = Constants.APIKeys.AWSAPIKey

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window!.rootViewController = self.createAndReturnRootVC()
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    private func createAndReturnRootVC() -> UIViewController {
        // Auth Status
        let cognitoAuth = AWSCognitoAuth.default()
        if AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().isSignedIn {
            return self.showLoggedInStateAndReturn(true)!
        } else {
            let loginVC = LoginViewController()
            return loginVC
        }
    }

    func enableCognitoClientWithAuthentication() {
        AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().initialize { (userState, error) in
            if let userState = userState {
                print("UserState: \(userState.rawValue)")
            }else if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().addUserStateListener(self) { (userState, info) in

            switch (userState) {
            case .signedOut:
                // user clicked signout button and signedout
                print("user signed out")
                self.window?.rootViewController = LoginViewController()

            case .signedOutUserPoolsTokenInvalid:
                print("need to login again.")
                AppController.sharedInstance.showLogin()
            //Alternatively call .showSignIn()
            case .signedIn:
                self.registerForPush()
                self.hydrateLocalUser()
                self.launchInWindow(aWindow: self.window)
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    self.window!.rootViewController = self.createAndReturnRootVC()//self.showLoggedInStateAndReturn(true)
//                    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
//                }
            default:
                print(userState)
                print("unsupported")
            }
        }
}

    @discardableResult func showLoggedInStateAndReturn(_ shouldReturn: Bool) -> UIViewController? {

        //AppController.sharedInstance.enableCognitoClientWithAuthentication()
        //self.registerForPush()

        self.tabBarController = ESTabBarController()
        //tabBarController.delegate = delegate
        self.tabBarController?.title = "Irregularity"
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage.image(with: UIColor("FFFFFF", alpha: 0.0)!)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage.image(with: UIColor("2A2A27")!)
        self.tabBarController?.shouldHijackHandler = {
            tabbarController, viewController, index in
            if index == 1 {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

            self.tabBarController?.didHijackHandler = {
            [weak tabBarController] tabbarController, viewController, index in

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                let newProjectNavCon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NewProjectViewController())
                newProjectNavCon.hero.isEnabled = true
                newProjectNavCon.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
                newProjectNavCon.hero.navigationAnimationType = .fade
                tabBarController?.present(newProjectNavCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        let centerVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())

        let v1 = centerVC
        let v2 = BaseViewController()
        let v3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ProfileViewController())

        v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarBouncesContentView(), title: "Projects", image: UIImage(named: "tabBarTruck"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tabBarTruck"))
        v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarIrregularityContentView(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "tabBarPlusButton"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tabBarPlusButton"))
        v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(TabBarBouncesContentView(), title: "Profile", image: UIImage(named: "tabBarProfile"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tabBarProfile"))

        self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers([v1, v2, v3], animated: true)

        if shouldReturn {
            return self.tabBarController
        } else {
            self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabBarController
            return nil
        }

    }
}
```